# Javascript put a variable in function name

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Is it possible to put a variable in a function name?
I'm trying to do like this

```
var **myvariable**;
function myFunction **myvariable** ()
```

Is there any way to put "myvariable" in this finction name?
Thanks

Comment: In global scope you could use a function expression: `window[<any expression here>] = function() {...}`, but you cannot do this for local variables or function declarations (*edit*: without using `eval` which you really shouldn't use in this case).

Comment: Will you be a little more specific?  Are you trying to do something like `eval("var myFunction" + variableName + " = function(){}");`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There are probably other ways to provide the same functionality.

Comment: You should ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you assumed was the proper solution. [What is the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Define your function in `var` way as following:

```
var testFunction = function(){
    //TODO
};
```

If your function defined under window scope, Transform into:

```
var name = 'testFunction';
window[name] = function(){
    //TODO
};
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your motivation is, but how about:

```
var foo;
foo = function bar(){

}
```

This assigns a function named `bar` to the variable `foo`. That means that:

```
>foo
function bar(){

}
```

while

```
>foo.name
"bar"
```